# What external touchpads work on Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, tap-to-click, doubleclick

By "work", I mean recognizing `clicks`, `taps`, `multi-finger clicks`, `multi-finger taps`, `simultaneous horizontal and vertical scroll using 2 fingers`, `pinch to unzoom and vice versa`.

By multi-finger, I think 3 fingers recognition is enough. 4 is a bonus :) Example: `3 fingers tap` to work as the middle click to fast close browser tabs or opening links in a new tab.

By external, I mean not built-in laptop touchpads.

So, know such a touchpad working on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware recommendation request.

Comment: It's a question about integrating hardware with **Ubuntu**. What's the right stackexchange place to ask such a question?

Comment: [hardwarerecs.se] maybe

Comment: Posted on hardware recommendation site: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6586/what-external-touchpads-work-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad on a Dell Vostro 5470, tested with 14.04.2, this touchpad works well with many gestures:

- One-finger tap
- Two-finger tap rightkey
- Two-finger scrolling
- Three-finger move / full screen / window switcher
- Four-finger dash

It does not work with two-finger zoom/pinch, however, I don't think it's supported as it's not listed in the [Ubuntu Wiki for Multitouch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch). So it looks like this touchpad fits your "working" criteria.

Here is the device information in case if you're interested:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003
```

Comment: Is it an internal or external touchpat? I'm searching for a well support external touchpad. One that can be used when the laptop's lid is closed.

Comment: Internal touchpad. Well, if that's the case, you should specify that in your question.